# OpenBUGS Error: "Sorry something went wrong in procedure UpdaterStd.Sample in module UpdaterSCAM"

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-networks, openbugs

I'm trying to run my below model code on OpenBUGS but I keep getting the error "Sorry something went wrong in procedure UpdaterStd.Sample in module UpdaterSCAM" when trying to update the model.

My model is supposed to be an adapted identity link to a log link that is adjusted for time (linear and quadratic term for time centered at 2 hours).

Any help is appreciated.

```
# Normal likelihood, log link, consistency model, with linear and quadratic terms of time – 2
# Random effects model for multi-arm trials
model{
  # *** PROGRAM STARTS
  for(i in 1:ns){ # LOOP THROUGH STUDIES
    w[i,1] <- 0 # adjustment for multi-arm trials is zero for control arm
    delta[i,1] <- 0 # treatment effect is zero for control arm
    mu[i] ~ dnorm(0,.0001) # vague priors for all trial baselines
    for (k in 1:na[i]) { # LOOP THROUGH ARMS
      var[i,k] <- pow(se[i,k],2) # calculate variances
      prec[i,k] <- 1/var[i,k] # set precisions
      y[i,k] ~ dnorm(theta[i,k],prec[i,k]) # normal likelihood
      log(theta[i,k]) <- mu[i] + delta[i,k] + (time[i,k] - 2) + pow((time[i,k] - 2),2) # model for linear and quadratic predictor with time effect centered at 2 hours
      dev[i,k] <- (y[i,k]-theta[i,k])*(y[i,k]-theta[i,k])*prec[i,k] #Deviance contribution
    }
    resdev[i] <- sum(dev[i,1:na[i]]) # summed residual deviance contribution for this trial
    for (k in 2:na[i]) { # LOOP THROUGH ARMS
      delta[i,k] ~ dnorm(md[i,k],taud[i,k]) # trial-specific LOR distributions
      md[i,k] <- d[t[i,k]] - d[t[i,1]] + sw[i,k] # log ratio of means of the kth treatment and 1st treatment
      taud[i,k] <- tau*2*(k-1)/k # precision of treat effects distributions (with multi-arm trial correction)
      w[i,k] <- (delta[i,k] - d[t[i,k]] + d[t[i,1]]) # adjustment for multi-arm RCTs
      sw[i,k] <- sum(w[i,1:k-1])/(k-1) # cumulative adjustment for multi-arm trials
    }
  }
  totresdev <- sum(resdev[]) #Total Residual Deviance
  d[1] <- 0 # treatment effect is zero for reference treatment
  for (k in 2:nt){ d[k] ~ dnorm(0,.0001) } # vague priors for treatment effects
  sd ~ dunif(0,5) # vague prior for between-trial SD.
  tau <- pow(sd,-2) # between-trial precision = (1/between-trial variance)
  for (j in 1:ns) {
    for (k in 1:na[j]) {
      time[j,k] ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001) # vague prior for time effect
    }
  }
#Ranking of treatments#
for(k in 1:nt) {
order[k]<- rank(d[],k)
# this is when the outcome is positive - omit 'nt+1-' when the outcome is negative
most.effective[k]<-equals(order[k],1)
for(j in 1:nt) {
effectiveness[k,j]<- equals(order[k],j)
}
}
for(k in 1:nt) {
for(j in 1:nt) {
cumeffectiveness[k,j]<- sum(effectiveness[k,1:j])
}
}
#SUCRAS#
for(k in 1:nt) {
SUCRA[k]<- sum(cumeffectiveness[k,1:(nt-1)]) /(nt-1)
}
# ranking on relative scale
for (k in 1:nt) {
# rk[k] < - nt+1 -rank(d[],k) # assumes events are “good”
rk[k] < - rank(d[],k) # assumes events are “bad”
best[k] < - equals(rk[k],1) #calculate probability that treat k is best
}
} # *** PROGRAM ENDS
```

I think the issue might be the following line

`log(theta[i,k]) <- mu[i] + delta[i,k] + (time[i,k] - 2) + pow((time[i,k] - 2),2)`

When I take out the log in front of theta, my model updates correctly, but when I put it back in it gives me the error. I need this to be a log link model, so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Is it possible that `log(theta[I,k])` is sufficiently large that it is producing infinite values.  It might make sense with `mu` having a prior variance of 10,000.  Also, what is the distributional characteristics of `y`?  Just or fun, what happens if you change the prior variance on `mu` to 100 instead?